# what does this mean? から+だから？

Tags: grammar

I found this in textbook.

> チェックインタイムが18.00からだから安いお得なプラン！

I think I can translate it to this:

> "Get special deal if you check in after 18.00"

but I don't get it, why would textbook use "だから” after から

Answer (score 3):

The first から is after a noun and represents the **beginning of a point in time**.

The second から is after a sentence and creates a subordinate clause indicating **reason (since/because/so).**

You're checking in (your check-in time is) after 18.00 so you get the good value plan.

Answer (score 2):

I'd parse it this way:

> ［チェックインタイムが18.00からだから（価格が）安い、］［お得な］プラン！
>   "(This is) a [bargain] plan, [where the price is low because the check-in time is after 18:00]."

... with both the relative clause 「チェックインタイムが18.00からだから（価格が）安い」 and the na-adjective 「お得な」 modifying the noun プラン. The subject of 安い is not a プラン.

A プラン is not low-priced/安い. The 価格/値段 is 安い in that プラン.

Rather than:

> ［チェックインタイムが18.00からだから、］安いお得なプラン！
>   "[The check-in time is after 18:00], so (this is) a low-priced bargain plan."

The から in 「18:00**から**」 is a case particle (格助詞) and means "after (a point in time)". The から in 「～だ**から**」 is a conjunctive particle (接続助詞), indicates reason, and translates to "because~~" or "~~so", as @G-Cam has said.

<sub>The copula, or the assertive auxiliary (断定の助動詞) 「だ」 is here because the second から is a conjunctive particle and needs to follow the terminal form of a conjugatable word (活用語の終止形).</sub>

Answer (score 1):

You should think like this "Because you check in after 18.00, you get a good bargain plan".

Answer (score 0):

質問に付されている原文は親しみ易くかつ簡潔であることから（すなわち、広告用のフレーズであると推測される）、固い言い方（店が客に口頭で伝える丁寧な言い方）に直した一例は「チェックインタイムは18：00からとなっております。そのため、お得なプランとさせていただいております。」となります。原文の「だから」は言い直し文の「そのため」に相当します。滞在時間が長ければその分お金を払わされるのではという感覚が我々にはあるから、13：00チェックインなどと比べると滞在時間が短いわけですから、安くあるべきことを客側は期待していることに対して、広告フレーズでアピールしている一文に思えます。

Comment: I like that you are not afraid to use Japanese to answer, and your explanation is pretty decent. However, with this being a page for learners of the language, answering a basic Japanese question in Japanese may be counterproductive for beginners. More advanced students, of course would love Japanese answers, but beginners may have a hard time with it.